# Reducing the number of x-axis ticks on Matplotlib plot from Panda

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, plot

I need to reduce or manually set the number of ticks on the x-axis of a Matplotlib line plot. This question has been asked many times here, I've gone through as many of those answers as I can find and through the Matplotlib docs and I haven't found a solution I can get working so I'm hoping for some help.

I have a Python dictionary with two sets of `key:value` pairs - `datetime.datetime` and `float`. There's hundreds of values in each set - but here's a snippet of the first elements just for reference:

```py
ws_kline_dict_01 = {'time': [datetime.datetime(2023, 2, 15, 10, 35, 8)], 'close': [22183.07]}
```

I've converted that dictionary to a Pandas dataframe so I can see it more easily in Jupyter and also stripped out the year, month and day from 'time' using:

```py
df_kline_dict_01 = pd.DataFrame(ws_kline_dict_01)
df_kline_dict_01['time'] = df_kline_dict_01['time'].dt.strftime('%H:%M:%S')
```

When I plot this via Matplotlib using 'time' as the x-axis - it prints every value as a tick which is way too cluttered (see 'Plot: Post-Panda format' below).

If I leave the `datetime.datetime` in its original form - Matplotlib seems to auto-select how many values it displays and it displays `"Day Hour:Minutes"` instead of `"Hour:Minutes:Seconds"` - which isn't working for me (see 'Plot: Pre-Panda format' below).

I've tried `plt.locator_params(axis='x', nbins=n)` - but this is giving me an error message:

```
"UserWarning: 'set_params()' not defined for locator of type <class 'matplotlib.category.StrCategoryLocator'>".
```

For reference - this is the code I'm using to produce the plot:

```
plt.plot(df_kline_dict_01['time'], df_kline_dict_01['close'], color = 'green', label = 'close')
plt.xticks(rotation=45, ha='right')
plt.show()
```

How do I (at least) reduce or (ideally) explicitly set the number of values/ticks shown on the x-axis?
Seems like this should be a pretty simple formatting task - but so far it's beating me and I'd appreciate some help getting this sorted.

[Plot: Pre-Panda format](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dXWh2.png)
[Plot: Post-Panda format](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gpwtA.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a possible solution using the [`.xaxis.set_major_locator()`](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.axis.Axis.set_major_locator.html) method. You can adjust the `max_xticks` variable to suit your use-case.

```py
...
df_kline_dict_01['time'] = df_kline_dict_01['time'].dt.strftime('%H:%M:%S')
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax.plot(df_kline_dict_01['time'], df_kline_dict_01['close'], color='green', label='close')

max_xticks = 6
ax.xaxis.set_major_locator(ticker.MaxNLocator(max_xticks))

plt.xticks(rotation=45, ha='right')
plt.show()
```

**Note:** I assigned `max_xticks = 6` so it helps you understand the code otherwise you could just set the value in `.MaxNLocator(6)` in the next line of code.

Answer (score 0):

Put some parameters for the locations like $plt.xticks(np.arange(min,max,step),rotation=45, ha='right')$
fill the min and max and steps as you wish